# Scale up or down text to fit label container JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Essentially what I want to achieve is want the font size to auto-adjust. I have a window that is 1920*1080, the label is full width and height. I enabled text-wrap because I'm planning on running lyrics in that software. So the idea is to make the text fit the container as big of a font as possible. Or if there is too much text, instead of vanishing to the bottom of the screen simply make the font smaller. I made the majority of the framework using scene builder, and it runs FXML. Thank you for your help in advance. maybe an image of what I have got will help.[Here is the image][1]

## Presentation.fxml

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.presentationController">
  <children>
     <Canvas fx:id="screen" height="1080.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" width="1920.0">
        <cursor>
           <Cursor fx:constant="NONE" />
        </cursor>
     </Canvas>
     <Label fx:id="displayText" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-2.0" layoutY="-4.0" prefHeight="1085.0" prefWidth="1924.0" text="Стучатся молитвы в небо, Касаясь святых небес! Звучат в них печаль и горе, И боль, как глубокий порез! Молитвы такие о детях, Родители в небо кричат! Они днем и  ночью взывают! Не могут сердца их молчать!" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="WORD_ELLIPSIS" wrapText="true">
        <font>
           <Font size="79.0" />
        </font>
        <padding>
           <Insets bottom="40.0" left="40.0" right="40.0" top="40.0" />
        </padding>
        <cursor>
           <Cursor fx:constant="NONE" />
        </cursor>
     </Label>
  </children>
  <cursor>
     <Cursor fx:constant="NONE" />
  </cursor>
```

## Presentation Controller.java

```
    package main;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class presentationController implements Initializable {

    @FXML public Canvas screen;
    @FXML public Label displayText;
    public drawScreen toscreen;

    public presentationController() {
        toscreen = new drawScreen();

    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        toscreen.initd(screen,displayText);
        toscreen.draw();
        toscreen.displayText("Стучатся молитвы в небо, Касаясь святых небес!\n" +
                "Звучат в них печаль и горе,\n" +
                "И боль, как глубокий порез!\n" +
                "Молитвы такие о детях,\n" +
                "Родители в небо кричат!\n" +
                "Они днем и  ночью взывают!\n" +
                "Звучат в них печаль и горе,\n" +
                "И боль, как глубокий порез!\n" +
                "Молитвы такие о детях,\n" +
                "Родители в небо кричат!\n" +
                "Они днем и  ночью взывают!\n" +
                "Звучат в них печаль и горе,\n" +
                "И боль, как глубокий порез!\n" +
                "Молитвы такие о детях,\n" +
                "Родители в небо кричат!\n" +
                "Они днем и  ночью взывают!\n" +
                "Не могут сердца их молчать");
        
    }


}
```

## DrawScreen

```
    package main;

import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import java.io.IOException;

public class drawScreen {
    Canvas previewScreen;
    Canvas displayScreen;
    public GraphicsContext g1;
    public GraphicsContext g2;
    public Label songLyricsPre;
    public Label songLyricsDis;
    public drawScreen(){

    }
    public void initp(Canvas previewScreen, Label text){
        this.previewScreen = previewScreen;
        this.songLyricsPre = text;
        System.out.println("Display Initialized: Preview");
    }
    public void initd( Canvas displayScreen, Label text){
        this.displayScreen = displayScreen;
        this.songLyricsDis = text;
        System.out.println("Display Initialized: Main");
    }
    public void draw(){
        Image i = new Image("/img/basic.png");

        try {
            if (previewScreen != null) {
                g1 = previewScreen.getGraphicsContext2D();
                g1.drawImage(i, 0, 0, previewScreen.getWidth(), previewScreen.getHeight());
            }
            if (displayScreen != null) {
                g2 = displayScreen.getGraphicsContext2D();
                g2.drawImage(i, 0, 0, displayScreen.getWidth(), displayScreen.getHeight());
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed to read Canvas");
        }
    }
    public void displayText(String text){
        try {
            if (previewScreen != null) {
                songLyricsPre.setText(text);
            }
            if (displayScreen != null) {
                songLyricsDis.setText(text);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed to read Canvas");
        }

    }



}
```

I hope this is enough to help you see whats going on
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKrLb.png

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: Wait what do u mean?

Comment: you are not serious in asking, are you :) Simply type the words into your favorite online search field to find out ..

Comment: dude, sorry I'm not great at the naming convention in java. I'm sort of a noob at this otherwise I wouldn't ask any questions here. I felt that I followed it well, maybe not, I have place to improve.

Comment: i just looked it up too, ill work on my code to follow those naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea behind my answer is that comparing the `width` and `height` properties of the `Label` and its container reflects how much of the text is being displayed (and how much is hidden).
When a the font of a label is doubled the `width` and `height` of the `Label` doubles.
[image]

If the text was wrapped perfectly with no extra spaces at the end of each line, the area of the label increase by a factor of four. I presume the layout node is kept constant, and the width of the label is also kept constant. Any extra text would cause an increase in height (and the text would go out of bounds of the layout node and out of view).

The goal is to keep the area of the `label` and container the same (so nothing is hidden). The ratio of their areas is simply the ratio of their heights as width is constant. Now the factor by which the font should be multiplied is the square root of the ratio of areas. (since area proportional to font^2).*Every time the `Label`'s height changes the changes to the font can be made accordingly as explained above.*

Now coming to the inherent error in this method because of the extra spaces at the end of each line. Every time the font is changed, the number of extra spaces might increase or decrease, causing a mismatch in the area of the `Label` and container even after computation. Re-computing tends to reduce this error. In my code, if the computed `font` is within 5% of the previous, the re-computation is not done.

Here's a working application:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller c = loader.getController();
        stage.setTitle("Hello World");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Controller {
    @FXML Label label;
    double font;
    int error = 5;//%
    @FXML Pane pane;
    @FXML TextField input;

    @FXML void initialize(){
        font = 15;
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + font);

        label.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            //The changed(...) method is called every time a change in the height is detected
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> value, Number number, Number t1) {
                double tentativeFont = font * Math.sqrt(pane.getHeight()/ label.getHeight());
                if (tentativeFont < font*(100-error)/100 || tentativeFont > font*(100+error)/100) {
                    font = tentativeFont;
                    label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + font);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="275" prefWidth="800" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <HBox>
        <Label fx:id="label" text="${input.text}" wrapText="true" prefWidth="400" />
        <TextField text="enter stuff" fx:id="input"/>
    </HBox>
</Pane>
```

While testing it, I found that the error might need to be tweaked. Large errors work well when there is very little text, and small errors for lot of text. You might want to program that too.